# Привязка свойства Source к триггерам

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, рефакторинг

Имеется следующий XAML-код:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem x:Name="tab1" Header="Image #1">
            <TabItem.Content>
                <Image Source="Images/fist_image.jpg"/>
            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name ="tab2" Header="Image #2">
            <TabItem.Content>
                <Image Source="Images/second_image.jpg"/>
            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

Свойство Content у обоих TabItem'ов практически одинаковы, за исключением пути к изображениям. Что бы не повторять код, я попытался реализовать нахождения пути к каждому изображению с помощью стилей и триггеров:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="findImage">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="TabItem.Name" Value="tab1">
                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="Images/fist_image.jpg"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="TabItem.Name" Value="tab2">
                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="Images/second_image.jpg"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Но теперь есть другая проблема - нужно реализовать привязку к свойства Source к триггеру.

Answer (score 0):

То, что вы делаете — неверное применение триггеров. Хотя триггерами и можно делать такое, они для этого не предназначены.

Правильный путь — использовать MVVM и привязываться к данным из VM. При этом ваш XAML будет выглядеть так:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Address}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

А ваш VM-класс — как-то так

```
class ImageVM
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Address { get; }
    public ImageVM(string name, string address) => (Name, Address) = (name, address);
}
```

и соответственно в главной VM

```
Images = new[]
{
    new ImageVM("Image #1", "Images/first_image.jpg"),
    new ImageVM("Image #2", "Images/second_image.jpg"),
}
```

Comment: Нельзя делать вот так - `Images = new[]`. Привязка к любой ненаблюдаемой коллекции дает утечку памяти же...

Comment: @PavelMayorov не уверен, что правильно вас понял. Где можно почитать об этом (" Привязка к любой ненаблюдаемой коллекции дает утечку памяти") подробнее?

Comment: @FoggyFinder: Это было в чате по C#, насколько я помню. Об этом, например, есть тут: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/09/04/fighting-common-wpf-memory-leaks-with-dotmemory/

Comment: @VladD точно, читал об этом, но не запомнил.